# Euler diagram and min-terms graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I learned about [Euler diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_diagram) just this week. It brought me some thoughts about boolean algebra when I saw [this figure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_diagram#/media/File:Couturat_1914_and_Venn_assignments1.jpg). Given an Euler diagram representation, it is possible to establish a interconnection graph between min-terms (the modern term for each diagram region). I do not know how to do it. Can you?

PS.: I also remembered of the 4 color theorem, but firstly we should have its graph representation...